# How do I make an object stick to slopes, and not walk up too steep slopes using unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, normals

I'm helping with a character controller, but we have run into problems when introducing slopes to it. When the player moves too fast down a slope, he will keep losing connection to the slope, because the gravity is not enough to keep him grounded. But increasing it is not an option. Another problem we have is defining the limits of the slopes he can climb.

The player is moved using Rigidbody.MovePosition. The exact behavior I'm looking for is: A hard threshold for the steepness the character can climb, a force that always keep the player on the ground, unless he falls off an edge.

I don't even know where to start making this. I googled around and found some people using raycasts and move the player down by the hit.distance, but I couldn't make it work.

I got started on the other problem, but soon became stuck too:
I got the normals from all the points the player is colliding with using `OnCollisionStay`:

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collisionInfo)
{
    foreach (ContactPoint contact in collisionInfo.contacts)
    {
        if(contact.normal.y > 0.9f && contact.normal.y < 1.1f)
        {
            Debug.Log("grounded");
        }
    }
}
```

This gave me a grounded message in the console, but I have no idea how to actually implement the constraints.

So yeah, I hope someone can help me out here, I'm sorry if this is formatted poorly, and if I'm missing something obvious.